# Converting C# List<string> To Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to convert a Model property of type List to a Javascript variable usable in that same view.
This is my model structure:

```
 public string Title { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
 public List<String> ImgLinks { get; set; }
```

I want a Javascript array or json of the ImgLinks property of my model. I have tried-

```
var imageLinks = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ImgLinks)));
```

But i get a syntax error warning. Can anyone please help me out with the conversion to both javascript array and json?

Comment: Which warning do you get?

Comment: The warning is syntax error

Comment: try JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ImgLinks))');

Comment: What does this line in the rendered page actually look like?

Comment: Now, i get no syntax error warning. I think i tried this earlier but i forgot that JSON.parse takes a string as parameter. Thanks @ShekharPankaj

Comment: I know this converts to JSON. Is there a way to convert the model property to javascript array directly?

Comment: Since JSON is a key value pair object, what will be the keys for my new json variable?

Comment: Try casting your List<String> to String[] before parsing.

Comment: You just need to remove the `;` at the end - `var imageLinks = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ImgLinks))`. But the 'syntax error' not a problem and the code will still run fine anyway. The `@foreach` loop solution in the  accepted answer is unnecessary.

Comment: @psyLogic, My comment was in relation to the question. But the comment your referring to is as a result of a suggestion to use `JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ImgLinks))');` which converts the model to a json string and then converts it to a javascript array. There is nothing wrong with your answer, but it is unnecessary (if OP wants to write 3 lines of code instead of 1, so be it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get rid of the 'syntax error' you just need to remove ; at the end

```
var imageLinks = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ImgLinks))
```

Despite the warning your code will run fine anyway.

Here's a different kind of solution to the problem if anyone's interested. You can loop through the razor collection and store the values in a Javascript Array like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myArray = [];

    @foreach (var link in Model.ImgLinks)
    {
        @:myArray.push("@link");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: what does the : before myArray mean? Is it a way to reference a javascript variable in razor for loop?

Comment: It says “this line is not *executed* as C#”, and should be emitted (in this case that is JS) after replacements. It might not necessarily be variable.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c “The @: outputs a single line of content containing plain text or unmatched HTML tags..” — so @: starting a line is pretty much the *opposite* of @ starting a line.

Comment: I never said it did not. I was correcting the incorrect assertion that @: had anything to do with *variables*. It does not. It relates to *text* emitted in the output.

Comment: I didn't read the edits you made later. Your comments didn't have all that information before. Of course you're right :)

Comment: Here's an answer with more information about the syntax, 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290189/what-does-mean-in-asp-net-mvc-razor/36290572

Answer (score 1):

There is a more elegant solution. You need to serialize your list to JSON:

```
var imageLinks = @Json.Encode(Model.ImgLinks); // <- annoying syntax error
```

So you did it right. Now to fix this syntax error I would suggest you to use simple javascript set function:

```
function set(value) {
    return value;
}

var imageLinks = set(@Json.Encode(Model.ImgLinks));
```

You can find more info about fixing this syntax error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617263/razor-syntax-error-serializing-asp-net-model-to-json-with-html-raw).