# What does @: mean in ASP.net MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on an ASP.net MVC Razor view that someone else wrote.  I see that it contains the following:

```
<span>
    @:
</span>
```

I know that the `@` symbol allows me to insert code into a view, but what does `@:` stand for?

Comment: [The @: sequence indicates that the line of content that follows should be treated as a content block:](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax) ("razor at colon" in Google).

Comment: @CodeCaster, add that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In MVC, `@` is the respective char that allows you to use razor inside HTML (inside a .cshtml) which in runtime (or precompiled) will be converted to c#.

With `@` you may write C# within HTML and with `@:` you may write HTML within C#.

Example:

```
@foreach (TestClass item in Model)
{
    @:@item.Code - @item.Name
}
```

Without the `@:` it wouldn't be possible to do this, since all the chars after the first `@` will be considered as C#.

This way you are saying that you are getting the two variables from `item` and placing the char `-` between them and the result is a content block (or html/text)

Comment: Is this the same as use <text> for write a block of HTML inside C# block of cshtml? Have this a similar purpose or not?

Comment: From what I remember <text> is exactly the same as @: but used for multi line.

Comment: Do elements rendered inside conditions like this not get target by custom TagHelper extensions?