# Wrap content with link if condition = true?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

What is the best way to wrap some elements inside a link, if a condition is true?

So, lets say i have this markup:

```
<div>
   <h1>Header</h1>
   <span>Subheader</span>
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

If i have a condition == true, then the whole above markup should be wrapped in a link, like so:

```
<a href="#">
    <div>
       <h1>Header</h1>
       <span>Subheader</span>
       <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

This is in Razor/C# code. What is the best way, without dublicating the markup?

Comment: `@if (condition) { <markup> }`?

Comment: Wont work.. it will complain that there is an open tag (<a>) that has not been closed

Comment: @EdPlunkett have you tried that? Does not work.

Comment: Save the value of `condition` in a bool variable then do what @EdPlunkett suggests.

Comment: @dcg have you tried it? It wont work that way :-)

Comment: @mxmissile why doesn't that work?

Comment: @johnny5 Our articulate friend must have meant that the markup within a pair of curly braces needs to have matched tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this is cheating, smelly and hack'ish but:

```
@if (condition) { @Html.Raw("<a href='#'>") }
    <div>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <span>Subheader</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
@if (condition) { @Html.Raw("</a>") }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little less hackish than @Html.Raw("…")

```
@if (condition) { 
    @:<a href="#"> 
}
<div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <span>Subheader</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
@if (condition) { 
    @:</a>
}
```

related: [What does @: mean in ASP.net MVC Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290189/what-does-mean-in-asp-net-mvc-razor)