# Get first value of Model's List in jQuery (document).ready using Razor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor

How can I get the value of the first item from the model's List? My ViewModel:

```
namespace TestWeb
{
  public class NavViewModel
  {
    public NavViewModel()
    {
      NavStepList = new List<NavStep>();
    }

    public List<NavStep> NavStepList { get; set; }
  }
}
```

In my View:

```
@using TestWeb
@model NavViewModel

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var Testvalue = @Model.NavStepList.First();
  });
</script>
```

I want the first value of `NavStepList`. However an error occurs when I call this function:

> TestWeb is undefined

I already test with testing value assign to `NavStepList` but the error still occurs.

My NavStep Class Property:

```
public class NavStep{
        public int NavStepId { get; set; }
        public int SortId { get; set; }
        public string StepName { get; set; }   
        public string IdentifierKey { get; set; }        
        public bool IsAvailible { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to coerce a class to a string. You need to retrieve the properties of the class and place them in separate JS variables.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please can you explain more detail?

Comment: I'd need to see the properties of your `NavStep` class to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: You can remove @using TestWeb line and then check.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert your server side view model to a javascript variable using the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.NavStepList.First()));
    });
</script>
```

and then you could access your model properties in javascript:

```
alert(myModel.NavStepId);
alert(myModel.SortId);
alert(myModel.StepName);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here @Model ought to refer to NavViewModel directly. Also, as Rory said, trying to assign a class, NavStep to a javascript variable isn't going to work out. What you probably want is:

```
var navStepId = @Model.First().NavStepId;
var sortId = @Model.First().SortId;
var stepName = "@Model.First().StepName"; //wrap strings in "" so javascript recognizes them as such
var identifierKey = "@Model.First().IdentifierKey";
var isAvailable = "@(Model.First().IsAvailable)" === '@true'; //method to convert c# true to javascript true
```

Comment: NavStepProperty model is not mention any where

Comment: I want all property of NavStep.

Comment: It's just an example I made up, I don't know what's in the class NavStep. Presumably var TestValue ought to be pointing to one of it's properties, (e.g. NavStepProperty)

Comment: @Jze in that case you'll probably want a couple of javascript variables to assign each property to, var testvalue1 = ... ;  var testvalue2 = ...; edit - have updated my answer since NavStep was included in question

Comment: @ButtDrivenDevelopment Thanks.I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: That's not very safe approach. Suppose for example that the `StepName` is `Step" ABC`. Then you will end up with the following broken javascript: `var stepName = "Step" ABC";`. And just imagine if the step name is `Step"; alert("You are XSSed baby"); var leftover="`. See my answer for the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Case**

The `@NavViewModel` model exists on server.
`jQuery` script are running  on client (browser)

**Problem**
How to access server side object on client?

**Solution** : **Serialize sever side object to client**

As we can not directly access server-side objects on client
We need to serialize the model (full/part).

```
var flatmodel = [@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.NavStepList.First()))][0];
```

Now flatmodel is JavaScript variable and we can access property via `flatmodel`.

Comment: Thanks,Can i use that json object in ajax.When i use this json object  in ajax,IE suddenly crush." Illegal invocation" error message show in Chrome.

Comment: how are you using this in ajax, can you please add that code part also, before also try to add  processData: false to ajax call?

Comment: @Jze Update in my answer can solve your problem, further you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617263/razor-syntax-error-serializing-asp-net-model-to-json-with-html-raw and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095567/can-i-post-a-json-model-from-html-raw-to-controller